# Is there a way to build an react-native expo app and save it do your ios device without a developer account?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, expo

I created an app and I can run it on my phone via the expo app but I can't actually save it to my device. I am aware that you can somehow get the ipa file and then add it to your account via XCode and it'll just have to be renewed every 7 days, but I have no idea how to get the ipa file and how to actually get that '7 day' developer account. Any ideas?